# reencode several videos with virtualdub?

Tags: video, batch, encoding, virtualdub

I have about 50 small videos (and a few large videos). I want to convert them all with the SAME settings. Its basically change audio to X with Y bitrate, change video to xvid. and do full processing on the video and audio. Then force the FPS to 15 since every program i tried (including virtualdub) thinks it 0.3 FPS.

How do i apply all of these settings to all of my files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this article : ["VirtualDub - What it is and how to use it"](http://www.animemusicvideos.org/guides/avtech3/amvapp-vdub.html#5) under the section "Exporting Video".

The interesting part for you is the last section called "Job Control", that describes how to process an entire directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question, but [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/) is excellent for batch transcoding.

Comment: I liked it however like EVERYTHING else (except virtualdub) it fails to convert my video :(. I got error 13 which says try another video source >_>.

Comment: Sounds like a missing codec.  Did you try installing the extra codecs pack http://mediacoder.sourceforge.net/dlcodecs.htm